# Callbacks in C# taking the callback directly in the method like in javascript

Tags: c#

I have the function in javascript which is something like

```
dothis(variablea, function(somevalue) {
    ..
});
```

which comes from `function dothis(variablea, callback) {..}`

So I want to fire `dothis` then callback the callback function later, when I get a response from a server.

How would I go about implementing something like this in C#, I've had a look at a couple of examples but I would like to pass the callback function directly into the method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely - you basically want [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx). For example:

```
public void DoSomething(string input, Action<int> callback)
{
    // Do something with input
    int result = ...;
    callback(result);
}
```

Then call it with something like this:

```
DoSomething("foo", result => Console.WriteLine(result));
```

(There are other ways of creating delegate instances, of course.)

Alternatively, if this is an asynchronous call, you might want to consider using async/await from C# 5. For example:

```
public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync(string input)
{
    // Do something with input asynchronously
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        await ... /* something to do with input */
    }
    int result = ...;
    return result;
}
```

The caller can then use that asynchronously too:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    int result1 = await DoSomethingAsync("something");
    int result2 = await AndSomethingElse(result1);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}
```

If you're basically trying to achieve asynchrony, async/await is a *much* more convenient approach than callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for delegates and lambda expressions:

```
void DoSomething(string whatever, Action<ResultType> callback) {

    callback(...);
}

DoSomething(..., r => ...);
```

However, you should usually return a `Task<T>` instead.

Comment: I believe that you either wanted to use `Func<TResult>` or `Action<TInput>` (not `Action<TResult>`)

Comment: @walkhard: No, the callback will *accept* the result of the method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant the naming, `Action` doesn't return value, so I find `ResultType` a bit misleading, perhaps I'd name it `InputType`, as this is the type of `callback`s parameter.

Comment: @walkhard: No, you've missed my point: it's the *result* of DoSomething which is being passed to the callback - so it's a perfectly fine name. The callback accepts the result type of the DoSomething method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand your way of thinking now. I was looking at it from different angle. Seems fine now, thanks.